# RegionPlot3D run forever when plotting 3D ParametricRegion

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, computational-geometry

when working with 2D, RegionPlot works fine with ParametricRegion as can be seen in this example:

```
r = ParametricRegion[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {{t, 0, 2 Pi}}];
RegionPlot[r]
```

however, when working with 3D ParametricRegion, the RegionPlot3D run forever.
check this example:

```
r2 = ParametricRegion[{Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], 
    Sin[v]}, {{u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}}];
    RegionPlot3D[r2]
```

nothing in the documentation said about functions  ParametricRegion and RegionPlot3D that they should not be use for 3D parametric Region.

any explanation why RegionPlot3D run non stop when plotting r2?

MMA 10 on windows 8.

thanks

Comment: what do you mean by RegionPlot[r2] is valid? in general, r2 is a valid region because you can do other operations with r2 such as RegionDistance and also RegionQ[r2] is True.

Comment: you can create ParametricRegion of any 3D paramedic function and then  try to plot it using RegionPlot3D.

Comment: I did not find any such thing in the docs. but even if the operation is not valid, I should have got and error message.

Comment: OK, I was just wondering.  I know `RegionPlot3D` works on `ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}]`, but being undocumented suggests there may be limitations.  I thought maybe you had seen an example.  Perhaps someone will enlighten us.

Comment: The code given in the Op question (`r2 = ParametricRegion[{Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {{u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}}];RegionPlot3D[r2]`) still doesn't work on Mma 10.4.1 (tried on Wolfram Development Platform)

Answer (score 5):

First, I should say that I could find no examples of using `RegionPlot3D` with regions in the documentation.  It works on some regions, not on others, and in this case runs longer than one wants to wait.

It runs nonstop because

```
Reduce[Exists[{u, v},
  x - Cos[u] == 0 && y - Cos[v] - Sin[u] == 0 &&  z - Sin[v] == 0 &&
   0 <= u <= 2*Pi && -Pi <= v <= Pi],
 {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

runs nonstop.  `RegionPlot3D` makes a call to `Reduce` like the above.

How to find the `Reduce` call:

```
r2 = ParametricRegion[{Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {{u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}}]

foo = Trace[
   TimeConstrained[RegionPlot3D[r2], 1],
   TraceInternal -> True];

Cases[foo, r_Reduce :> HoldForm[r], Infinity]
```

The output will produce a similar `Reduce` call with local variables in the `` Region`Private` `` context instead of `u`, `v`, `x`, `y`, and `z`.

---

A potential issue, should `Reduce` ever return something useful, is that the `ParametricRegion` `r2` is a surface in space:

```
RegionDimension[r2]
(* 2 *)

RegionEmbeddingDimension[r2]
(* 3 *)
```

`RegionPlot3D` plots a solid region by showing its surface.  It's not clear to me that it would work with an input that is a surface and not a description of a solid region.

`DiscretizeRegion[r2]` might work, but it makes the same call to `Reduce` as `RegionPlot3D`.

Another issue is that the "inside" of `r2` is not well-defined.  Below we see the surface intersects itself and the inside becomes the outside, so to speak, shown by the coloring due to `FaceForm`.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]},
 {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Red, Blue]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I get a 3D plot for r3 using RegionPlot3D[r3]. this mean that RegionPlot3D works find with ParametricRegion.

Comment: yes you are correct. thanks

Comment: @Algohi `ParametricRegion[{u, v, r}, {{u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, {r, 0, 1}}]` gives an `ImplicitRegion` object. I have not yet seen `RegionPlot3D` work correctly on a `ParametricRegion` object. I think it cannot work, because it is designed for regions of positive volume ('cannot plot regions of measure 0').