# Parametric Region from Surface of Revolution

Tags: plotting, geometry

I would like to create a region defined by the volume inside (or outside) a surface of revolution, and am struggling with understanding how the `ParametricRegion`  function works. The help documentation only gives 2D examples unfortunately.

For example I would like to take the surface defined by:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[s] (1 + t^2), Sin[s] (1 + t^2),t}, {t, -2, 2}, {s, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

and then us this to define one of my region boundaries.

If I define a 3D region like:

```
reg = ParametricRegion[{Cos[s] (1 + t^2), Sin[s] (1 + t^2), t}, {{t, -2, 2}, {s, 0, 2 \[Pi]}}]
```

and then try to plot this using `RegionPlot[reg]`

I get errors related that say such a region cannot be automatically discretised and that this is not a valid region to plot.

As far as I understand this code should give me the surface ? But does anyone know how one can define the volume inside, and then visualise this using `RegionPlot` or `DiscretizeRegion` ?

Comment: It's not a closed surface.  What you mean by "inside"?

Comment: @MichaelE2. Sorry, perhaps this was unclear. By inside I mean the region close to the z-axis. I would also like to cap the region eventually, to make a closed shape (i.e. constraining to -a<z<a for "a" being some numerical value. In 2D it seems that it is not important whether surfaces are closed or not (i.e. one can define regions such that x<0)

Comment: @MichaelE2. I just saw this post [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57572/regionplot3d-run-forever-when-plotting-3d-parametricregion), which I guess is related (could be that my question somewhat duplicates that one). I also realised I was using RegionPlot (defined only for 2D) and not RegionPlot3D. In the end I guess the question comes down to whether parametric regions can be plotted using RegionPlot3D or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that you have defined isn't a 3D region:

```
In[1]:= reg = ParametricRegion[{Cos[s] (1 + t^2), Sin[s] (1 + t^2), t},
         {{t, -2, 2}, {s, 0, 2 \[Pi]}}];
In[2]:= RegionDimension[reg]
Out[2]= 2
```

It's a 2D region, because you've defined a surface of revolution.  What's not very well documented, unfortunately, is that RegionPlot(3D) only support full dimensional regions.  I presume what you're interested in is the volum of revolution which is swept out by a ray from the z-axis, which is the following:

```
In[3]:= reg = ParametricRegion[{u Cos[s] (1 + t^2), u Sin[s] (1 + t^2), t}, 
          {{t, -2, 2}, {s, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {u, 0, 1}}];
In[4]:= RegionDimension[reg]
Out[4]= 3
```

This can now be plotted using RegionPlot3D.  For example, the following looks reasonably nice:

```
RegionPlot3D[reg, MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotPoints -> 35, 
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-2, 2}}]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure what region is required.

```
region1 = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   0 < x^2 + y^2 < (z^2 + 1)^2, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -2, 2}}];
region2 = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 > (z^2 + 1)^2, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -2, 2}}];
opts = Sequence[Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 400]
Column[{RegionPlot3D[region1, PlotPoints -> 40, PlotStyle -> LightRed,
    Evaluate@opts],
  RegionPlot3D[region2, PlotPoints -> 40, 
   PlotStyle -> {LightBlue, Opacity[0.5]}, Evaluate@opts],
  RegionPlot3D[{region1, region2}, PlotPoints -> 40, 
   PlotStyle -> {LightRed, {LightBlue, Opacity[0.5]}}, Evaluate@opts]

  }]
```

[image]

Comment: The First image was the one I was looking for, although in fact either of the surfaces is usable for my calculations. Many thanks!